# clear phpThumb cache regularly with cron job

Tags: caching, cron, phpthumb

I am using phpThumb on a client website, and as it is a very image heavy application the cache gets huge quick.  Today the thumbs stopped working and I had rename the cache folder, as the folder was too big to delete via ftp.  I renamed it cache_old and am trying to delete it now via ssh.  I recreated the cache folder and everything worked fine again.

Since it seems it stops working when the cache folder is too full, plus just to keep the server tidy, I would like to setup a daily cron job to clear files from the cache folder.  I have no idea how to do this though and haven't been able to find an answer yet..

The cache folder has a file in it called index.php which I assume needs to stay, plus a sub folder called source, which again has a file called index.php, again I assumed that needs to be there.  So I need a command that will delete everything BUT those files.

Any guidance on how to set this up would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Christine

P.S. The site is hosted on DreamHost, and I have set other jobs up via there cronjob panel, and I do have SSH access if setting it up that way is easier. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

it's possible to do this in one command but it's more obviously.

```
 rm `find /path_to_cache_folder/ -type f | grep -v 'index.php'`
 rm `find /path_to_cache_folder/source -type f | grep -v 'index.php'`
```

or in one cron job

```
rm `find /path_to_cache_folder/ -type f | grep -v 'index.php'` && rm `find /path_to_cache_folder/source -type f | grep -v 'index.php'`
```